# Word for time that performers must arrive for a show or event

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the term for the time that performers must arrive for a show?

For example, "Show starts at 8, [WORD] for cast and crew is 7pm not a millisecond later!"

Similarly, a "curtain call" is at the end of a show, when performers step out from behind the curtain, and take a bow.

What is the term on Broadway for the time that performers are required to arrive? Ty.

Answer (score 4):

**call time / call**

> **call time** (n.)

> *Theatre and Film.* The time at which cast and crew are required to be
> at the theatre or on set.  OED

> (Performing arts) The expected time of arrival for participants in a
> performance event, e.g., a play or concert.
>
> *The performance starts at 2 pm; call time is 11 am for crew, noon for musicians.* [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/call_time)

> **call** (n.)
>
> **2.** The time when personnel must report: *the **call time***; *union call*; i.e., the time when union stagehands and technicians, members of IATSE, must report for work. They are "on the clock" at the appointed call time. [*Blumfeld's
> Dictionary of Acting and Show Business*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Blumenfeld_s_Dictionary_of_Acting_and_Sh/oT_rZizNcBAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22call%20time%22%20was%20theater&pg=PA44&printsec=frontcover) (2009)

---

> The time the actors arrive at the theatre is known as their **call**,
> and the time the play starts is called **curtain**. If they have a lot
> of makeup to apply, the actor's **call** might be several hours before
> curtain; if they have little hair or makeup to apply, **call** may be as little as forty-five minutes beforehand. [William Downs et al.; *The Art of Theatre*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Art_of_Theatre_Then_and_Now/VRoKAAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22call%22%20was%20one%20hour%20before%20curtain&pg=PA112&printsec=frontcover) (2007)

> At the end of every rehearsal, you should remind the crew of their
> next **call time**. [John Holloway; *Illustrated Theatre Production
> Guide*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Illustrated_Theatre_Production_Guide/sXYqBgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22call%20time%22%20was%20theater&pg=PA191&printsec=frontcover) (2013)

> The director or stage manager gives you a **call time** to get to the theater for this opening might performance and every other performances as well. Some actors like to get to the theater before the **call time** so
> that they have enough time to prepare. [Katherine Mayfield; *Acting A
> to Z*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Acting_A_to_Z_Revised_Second_Edition/LPZ_fZA7wIsC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22call%20time%22%20was%20theater&pg=PT113&printsec=frontcover) (2010)

Answer (score 1):

The AHD has this definition of *call*:

> 12. A notice of rehearsal times posted in a theater.

This would seem to apply to your question.

https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=call

Comment: The AHD definition seems to demand a concrete referent.